# How do I download all releases (in fact all tags) of a project at a time?

Tags: github, tags, project

I need to download all releases (in fact all tags) of a project from github repository.
So I need commands or scripts that provide all the tag names of a given project and download them automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clone the entire git repository to a local directory on your machine with `git clone --no-single-branch`
2. Now you have all the data downloaded in git format
3. Use the `git tag` command to list all the tags
4. Use the `git archive` command to create an archive (tar or zip) of each tagged release (Hint: Use shell or batch scripting to loop over the output from `git tag`)